# JAXB "grammar is not specified"

Tags: java, netbeans, xsd, jaxb

im trying to generate JAXB classes from an xsd by Netbeans but im getting

```
C:\datos\NetBeansProjects\RegistradoresWSSERCON\nbproject\xml_binding_build.xml:15: grammar is not specified
```

Relative to the code lane:

```
    <xjc destdir="build/generated/jaxbCache/ACK" catalog="catalog.xml">
```

This is the xsd im trying to use:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wmh="http://www.wmhelp.com/2003/eGenerator" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="registroResponse">    
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="codigosError" nillable="true" type="tns:registroError"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="idTramite" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="xml" type="xs:base64Binary"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="registroError">   
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="codigo" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="descripcion" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="detalles" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Anyone knows what is happening ? Tyvm in advance

Edit: xml_binding_build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!--
        *** GENERATED FROM xml_binding_cfg.xml - DO NOT EDIT  ***
        *** Configure thru JAXB Wizard.                       ***
    --><project name="RegistradoresWSSERCON_jaxb" default="default" basedir=".">
<target name="xjc-typedef-target" depends="-init-project">
    <typedef classname="com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask" name="xjc" xmlns:s="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/JAXBWizConfig">
        <classpath path="${jaxbwiz.xjcdef.classpath}"/>
    </typedef>
</target>
<target name="jaxb-clean-code-generation" depends="clean,jaxb-code-generation"/>
<target name="jaxb-code-generation" depends="xjc-typedef-target,-do-init,-init-macrodef-javac">
    <mkdir dir="${build.generated.sources.dir}/jaxb" xmlns:s="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/JAXBWizConfig"/>
    <mkdir dir="build/generated/jaxbCache" xmlns:s="http://xml.netbeans.org/schema/JAXBWizConfig"/>
    <mkdir dir="build/generated/jaxbCache/ACK"/>
    <xjc destdir="build/generated/jaxbCache/ACK" catalog="catalog.xml">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="${src.dir}"/>
            <pathelement path="${jaxbwiz.xjcrun.classpath}"/>
        </classpath>
        <arg value="-xmlschema"/>
        <schema file=""/>
        <depends file=""/>
        <produces dir="build/generated/jaxbCache/ACK"/>
    </xjc>
    <copy todir="${build.generated.sources.dir}/jaxb">
        <fileset dir="build/generated/jaxbCache/ACK"/>
    </copy>
    <!--*** Web project javac macro does not support sourcepath attribute, so do not pass "sourcepath=${src.dir}"-->
</target>
```

Comment: I believe the error means that it cannot find the XSD file. --- Also, does your XSD file really start with spaces before the `<?xml ...?>` tag, like it shows here?

Comment: Please post the entire xjc fragment

Comment: @Andreas, nope, it doesnt have spaces before, thats an ident mistake.

Comment: Seriously, why downvote ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<schema file=""/>` provide an empty path, jaxb has nothing to process.

xjc task documentation [here](https://jaxb.java.net/nonav/2.0.2/docs/xjcTask.html).

```
Attribute   Description
------------------------------------------
schema      A schema file to be compiled. A file name (can be relative to the build script base directory), or an URL. This or nested <schema> elements are required.
destdir     Generated code will be written under this directory. If you specify target="abc/def" and package="org.acme", then files are generated to abc/def/org/acme.
catalog     Specify the catalog file to resolve external entity references. Support TR9401, XCatalog, and OASIS XML Catalog format. See the catalog-resolver sample for details.
```

[Netbeans JAXB Wizard FAQ is here](http://wiki.netbeans.org/JAXBWizard#JAXB_Wizard).

[This article shows a dialog box of the wizard with a path and a browse button.](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/jaxb_wizard_scheduled_for_netbeans)

Comment: OP could have a nested `<schema>` element. We can see that the `<xjc>` element is not ended, so we're obviously not seeing all of it.

Comment: Yes, i have <schema file=""/> but i thought that it was autogenerated by jaxb bingind plugin in Netbeans

Comment: "" isn't a valid path... your problem is related to the generation of the xjc fragment

Comment: @Aubin Its not supposed to be autogenerated by the plugin?

Comment: Yes, it's not a JAXB nor a XLC problem but a plugin configuration problem.

Comment: I have managed to fix the problem by deleting the project and adding it again, thx for your help @Aubin

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you provide xmlschema argument:

```
xjc -d src -p com.schema -xmlschema schema-file.xsd
```